# Angular Typescript array only adds last element on array.push()

Tags: node.js, arrays, angular, typescript

i have a function called in ngInit(), that fills an array with objects of a class with values generated in a **for loop**, using **array.push()**.

However, once the for loop completes, all the array items are the last-added instance of the class.

**Class def**

```
class ABC{
time: number;
id: number;
 }
```

**Function def**

```
addToArray(){
 let arrayTemp : ABC[]= [];
 let tempClass ={} as ABC;

 for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 
   tempClass.timei+1;
   tempClass.id=i;

    let val=i;
    arrayTemp.push(tempClass);
    console.log(arrayTemp[val]);   // here class objects displayed correctly
}

   console.log(arrayTemp);  // here all elements are just the last added class object
  
  }
 }
```

**Output of *console.log(arrayTemp[val])***

[image]

**Output of *console.log(arrayTemp) after the for loop***

[image]

I'm not sure why this happens, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: each element in the array contains the same instance of the ABC class. So each time you update the tempClass values, each element will reflect the change.

Comment: put `let tempClass ={} as ABC;` inside the for loop if you want a new instance of the class with each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: @cWerning Why have you answered it in a comment? Just post the answer.

Comment: @AustinTFrench cuz I don't follow rules from the man

Comment: Javascript is not C++, read the docs on what a function does, does it make a copy of the argument or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you modify Class directly, like here

```
   tempClass.timei+1;
   tempClass.id=i;
```

You are modifying the *existing* class instance.
Because you add this already existing instance in array with
`arrayTemp.push(tempClass);`
It means you edit the class you created in the beginning with
`let tempClass ={} as ABC;`

What you actually want to do, is create a new class instance for each iteration, like so

```
addToArray(){
 let arrayTemp : ABC[]= [];

 for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   // create new instance of class for each iteration
   let tempClass = new ABC();
   tempClass.timei+1;
   tempClass.id=i;

    let val=i;
    arrayTemp.push(tempClass);
    console.log(arrayTemp[val]);   // here class objects displayed correctly
}

   console.log(arrayTemp);  // here all elements are just the last added class object
  
  }
 }
```

Edit:
Don't forget to create your class with `new` keyword! If you do intialization directly as `let tempClass ={} as ABC;` you wont get actual representation of a class, you only get empty object that only *looks* like a ABC class to typescript.

Comment: Thanks, fairly new to typescript, so this explanation helped tons!